# Matlab Codegen Eig Function - Is this a Bug?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following minimal example:

```
function CoderEigFail() %#codegen
A = [0 sqrt(2); sqrt(2) 0];
[B C] = eig(A)
```

When I compile this via `codegen CoderEigFail.m` and run it, I get a different matrix B than I get when I run the original Matlab file instead. In particular, for the mex file I get B = [1 1; -1 1], while for the Matlab file I get B = [-0.7071 0.7071; 0.7071 0.7071]. I have Matlab R2011a running on MacOSx Mountain Lion.

Can anyone reproduce/explain this behavior? Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: Interesting "bug". Understand however that an eigenvector is just that, a vector. So essentially just a direction which can be arbitrarily scaled and still be valid (in the sense that the direction <1,2> is identical to the direction <2,4> and so on. Eigenvectors are only unique to within a scaling factor. In my experience Matlab always chooses to scale these eigenvectors (the columns of B) so that their 2-norm is unity. Apparently the compiled version either doesn't scale or it scales differently. Hopefully someone else can fill out more details on why the differences in scaling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not a bug.

As Stuart pointed out in the comment to the question, eigenvectors are generally normalized. This is pointed out in a note in the documentation of [`eig()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eig.html).

The difference in behavior with the compiled version is a documented feature in "[Expected Differences in Behavior After Compiling MATLAB Code](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/expected-differences-in-behavior-after-compiling-your-matlab-code.html#bshop6t)" under "For certain advanced library functions".

This behavior is simply acknowledged but not justified or explained.