# Matlab Codgen eig() function - strange behaviour

Tags: matlab, code-generation, eigenvector, eigenvalue, matlab-coder

First, don't be fooled by the long post, there is not a lot of code just an observation of results so there are few example matrices.

This is a bit related to this question: [Matlab Codegen Eig Function - Is this a Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065641/matlab-codegen-eig-function-is-this-a-bug)

I know that mex/C/C++ translated [eig()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) function may not return the same eigenvectors when using the same function in MATLAB and that's fine, but i am puzzled with results I'm getting.

**First this simple example:**

```
Output
% c = diagonal matrix of eigenvalues
% b = matrix whose columns are the corresponding right eigenvectors

function [ b, c ] = eig_test(a)
    [b, c] = eig(a);
end
```

Running as is for `[b,c] = eig_test(magic(5))` this returns:

```
b =
-0.4472    0.0976   -0.6330    0.6780   -0.2619
-0.4472    0.3525    0.5895    0.3223   -0.1732
-0.4472    0.5501   -0.3915   -0.5501    0.3915
-0.4472   -0.3223    0.1732   -0.3525   -0.5895
-0.4472   -0.6780    0.2619   -0.0976    0.6330

c =
65.0000         0         0         0         0
      0  -21.2768         0         0         0
      0         0  -13.1263         0         0
      0         0         0   21.2768         0
      0         0         0         0   13.1263
```

Translating that to mex function and running `eig_test_mex(magic(5))` returns:

```
b =
0.4472 + 0.0000i   0.0976 + 0.0000i  -0.6330 + 0.0000i   0.6780 + 0.0000i  -0.2619 + 0.0000i
0.4472 + 0.0000i   0.3525 + 0.0000i   0.5895 + 0.0000i   0.3223 + 0.0000i  -0.1732 + 0.0000i
0.4472 + 0.0000i   0.5501 + 0.0000i  -0.3915 + 0.0000i  -0.5501 + 0.0000i   0.3915 + 0.0000i
0.4472 + 0.0000i  -0.3223 + 0.0000i   0.1732 + 0.0000i  -0.3525 + 0.0000i  -0.5895 + 0.0000i
0.4472 + 0.0000i  -0.6780 + 0.0000i   0.2619 + 0.0000i  -0.0976 + 0.0000i   0.6330 + 0.0000i


c =
65.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i -21.2768 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i -13.1263 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  21.2768 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  13.1263 + 0.0000i
```

Now here the values are actually the same (with exception of first vector that differs only in - sign) but from where are these complex imaginary parts coming from?

**Second example:**

Using the same function as above, the input matrix is now this one below instead of `magic(5)`:

```
input_matrix =
 0.0440   -0.0000    0.0486    0.0752    0.0848    0.0881    0.0883    0.0874    0.0856    0.0832    0.0805    0.0775    0.0742    0.0709    0.0676    0.0644    0.0612    0.0580    0.0548    0.0518    0.0487
-0.0000         0   -0.0000   -0.0000         0   -0.0000   -0.0000         0         0   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000         0         0   -0.0000   -0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000         0
 0.0486   -0.0000    0.1253    0.1231    0.1128    0.1028    0.0940    0.0867    0.0803    0.0747    0.0697    0.0651    0.0609    0.0570    0.0535    0.0503    0.0473    0.0446    0.0421    0.0397    0.0375
 0.0752   -0.0000    0.1231    0.3049    0.2850    0.2641    0.2454    0.2297    0.2157    0.2034    0.1924    0.1820    0.1723    0.1636    0.1556    0.1482    0.1414    0.1351    0.1292    0.1237    0.1186
 0.0848         0    0.1128    0.2850    0.3941    0.3685    0.3451    0.3253    0.3077    0.2921    0.2780    0.2646    0.2521    0.2407    0.2303    0.2207    0.2119    0.2036    0.1959    0.1887    0.1819
 0.0881   -0.0000    0.1028    0.2641    0.3685    0.4420    0.4161    0.3943    0.3746    0.3571    0.3413    0.3262    0.3120    0.2990    0.2871    0.2762    0.2661    0.2566    0.2478    0.2396    0.2318
 0.0883   -0.0000    0.0940    0.2454    0.3451    0.4161    0.4705    0.4474    0.4266    0.4079    0.3910    0.3748    0.3595    0.3455    0.3326    0.3208    0.3098    0.2996    0.2900    0.2811    0.2726
 0.0874         0    0.0867    0.2297    0.3253    0.3943    0.4474    0.4918    0.4701    0.4507    0.4330    0.4160    0.3999    0.3851    0.3716    0.3591    0.3474    0.3366    0.3265    0.3170    0.3080
 0.0856         0    0.0803    0.2157    0.3077    0.3746    0.4266    0.4701    0.5067    0.4868    0.4686    0.4511    0.4343    0.4190    0.4049    0.3919    0.3798    0.3686    0.3580    0.3481    0.3387
 0.0832   -0.0000    0.0747    0.2034    0.2921    0.3571    0.4079    0.4507    0.4868    0.5182    0.4997    0.4817    0.4645    0.4487    0.4343    0.4209    0.4084    0.3968    0.3859    0.3757    0.3660
 0.0805   -0.0000    0.0697    0.1924    0.2780    0.3413    0.3910    0.4330    0.4686    0.4997    0.5269    0.5087    0.4911    0.4751    0.4603    0.4466    0.4339    0.4220    0.4108    0.4003    0.3905
 0.0775   -0.0000    0.0651    0.1820    0.2646    0.3262    0.3748    0.4160    0.4511    0.4817    0.5087    0.5317    0.5140    0.4977    0.4827    0.4688    0.4559    0.4438    0.4325    0.4218    0.4117
 0.0742         0    0.0609    0.1723    0.2521    0.3120    0.3595    0.3999    0.4343    0.4645    0.4911    0.5140    0.5337    0.5173    0.5021    0.4881    0.4750    0.4628    0.4514    0.4406    0.4304
 0.0709         0    0.0570    0.1636    0.2407    0.2990    0.3455    0.3851    0.4190    0.4487    0.4751    0.4977    0.5173    0.5351    0.5199    0.5057    0.4926    0.4803    0.4687    0.4578    0.4475
 0.0676   -0.0000    0.0535    0.1556    0.2303    0.2871    0.3326    0.3716    0.4049    0.4343    0.4603    0.4827    0.5021    0.5199    0.5362    0.5220    0.5087    0.4963    0.4847    0.4737    0.4634
 0.0644   -0.0000    0.0503    0.1482    0.2207    0.2762    0.3208    0.3591    0.3919    0.4209    0.4466    0.4688    0.4881    0.5057    0.5220    0.5370    0.5237    0.5112    0.4995    0.4885    0.4781
 0.0612         0    0.0473    0.1414    0.2119    0.2661    0.3098    0.3474    0.3798    0.4084    0.4339    0.4559    0.4750    0.4926    0.5087    0.5237    0.5376    0.5251    0.5134    0.5023    0.4918
 0.0580         0    0.0446    0.1351    0.2036    0.2566    0.2996    0.3366    0.3686    0.3968    0.4220    0.4438    0.4628    0.4803    0.4963    0.5112    0.5251    0.5381    0.5263    0.5152    0.5047
 0.0548         0    0.0421    0.1292    0.1959    0.2478    0.2900    0.3265    0.3580    0.3859    0.4108    0.4325    0.4514    0.4687    0.4847    0.4995    0.5134    0.5263    0.5384    0.5273    0.5167
 0.0518   -0.0000    0.0397    0.1237    0.1887    0.2396    0.2811    0.3170    0.3481    0.3757    0.4003    0.4218    0.4406    0.4578    0.4737    0.4885    0.5023    0.5152    0.5273    0.5387    0.5281
 0.0487         0    0.0375    0.1186    0.1819    0.2318    0.2726    0.3080    0.3387    0.3660    0.3905    0.4117    0.4304    0.4475    0.4634    0.4781    0.4918    0.5047    0.5167    0.5281    0.5389
```

Running for `[b,c] = eig_test(input_matrix)` returns:

```
b =
 0.0000   -0.0085   -0.0117   -0.0166   -0.0251   -0.0442    0.1334    0.9260   -0.1493    0.0548   -0.0283    0.0382    0.0170    0.0977    0.1285   -0.1697    0.1100   -0.1149    0.0635    0.0881    0.0424
 1.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
-0.0000    0.0020    0.0029    0.0042    0.0067    0.0125   -0.0404   -0.2919    0.0495   -0.0178    0.0219    0.0179    0.1086    0.2330    0.4679   -0.5139    0.4286   -0.3220    0.2241    0.1454    0.0392
 0.0000    0.0001    0.0001    0.0002    0.0003    0.0005   -0.0010   -0.0102   -0.0017   -0.0143   -0.0484   -0.1305   -0.2829   -0.4495   -0.4237    0.0949    0.2592   -0.3986    0.4161    0.3145    0.1072
-0.0000    0.0001    0.0002    0.0003    0.0006    0.0005   -0.0076   -0.0267    0.0241    0.0641    0.1763    0.3391    0.4702    0.3538   -0.0858    0.3847   -0.2103   -0.1113    0.3607    0.3698    0.1531
 0.0000    0.0001    0.0001    0.0003   -0.0001    0.0044    0.0173   -0.0280   -0.0740   -0.2070   -0.3832   -0.4693   -0.2586    0.1790    0.3224    0.0909   -0.3636    0.1799    0.2003    0.3654    0.1849
 0.0000    0.0001    0.0001   -0.0000    0.0029   -0.0168   -0.0758    0.0155    0.2178    0.4038    0.4549    0.1676   -0.2686   -0.2836    0.1914   -0.2398   -0.2029    0.3295    0.0210    0.3288    0.2079
-0.0000    0.0001    0.0000    0.0015   -0.0114    0.0623    0.1958   -0.0857   -0.3987   -0.4488   -0.1154    0.3136    0.2223   -0.2549   -0.1457   -0.2976    0.0628    0.3254   -0.1323    0.2755    0.2255
-0.0000    0.0001    0.0005   -0.0058    0.0419   -0.1658   -0.3782    0.0966    0.4538    0.1163   -0.3266   -0.1826    0.2893    0.0922   -0.2891   -0.1140    0.2566    0.2114   -0.2394    0.2128    0.2385
 0.0000    0.0001   -0.0020    0.0224   -0.1169    0.3338    0.4695   -0.1012   -0.1655    0.3142    0.1810   -0.3027   -0.0583    0.2923   -0.1581    0.1266    0.3013    0.0487   -0.2951    0.1468    0.2482
-0.0000   -0.0003    0.0085   -0.0675    0.2572   -0.4725   -0.2826   -0.0124   -0.2658   -0.2251    0.2927    0.0580   -0.2952    0.1782    0.0838    0.2657    0.2098   -0.1089   -0.3025    0.0811    0.2552
 0.0000    0.0016   -0.0282    0.1667   -0.4258    0.4018   -0.1483    0.0743    0.2952   -0.2511   -0.1046    0.3011   -0.1748   -0.0861    0.2409    0.2463    0.0445   -0.2242   -0.2699    0.0183    0.2593
-0.0000   -0.0060    0.0796   -0.3248    0.4873   -0.0371    0.3582   -0.0471    0.1556    0.1904   -0.3026    0.1397    0.1135   -0.2564    0.2258    0.1072   -0.1212   -0.2793   -0.2087   -0.0393    0.2613
-0.0000    0.0202   -0.1839    0.4791   -0.2780   -0.3330   -0.0369   -0.0733   -0.2823    0.2701   -0.0569   -0.1694    0.2707   -0.2224    0.0779   -0.0674   -0.2333   -0.2741   -0.1307   -0.0908    0.2618
 0.0000   -0.0569    0.3438   -0.4801   -0.1422    0.2530   -0.3217    0.0344   -0.1598   -0.0783    0.2433   -0.2745    0.1829   -0.0400   -0.1011   -0.1994   -0.2669   -0.2193   -0.0462   -0.1354    0.2611
 0.0000    0.1366   -0.4999    0.2085    0.3815    0.1931    0.0665    0.0563    0.2298   -0.2886    0.2299   -0.1025   -0.0438    0.1536   -0.2162   -0.2443   -0.2244   -0.1314    0.0362   -0.1730    0.2594
-0.0000   -0.2750    0.5187    0.2125   -0.1234   -0.2906    0.3002   -0.0330    0.2275   -0.0976   -0.0389    0.1510   -0.2225    0.2429   -0.2221   -0.1981   -0.1272   -0.0288    0.1102   -0.2036    0.2569
 0.0000    0.4544   -0.2791   -0.3911   -0.2949   -0.1393   -0.0141   -0.0736   -0.1126    0.2031   -0.2494    0.2586   -0.2356    0.1924   -0.1303   -0.0881   -0.0057    0.0716    0.1710   -0.2273    0.2536
-0.0000   -0.5901   -0.1434    0.0927    0.2187    0.2750   -0.2874   -0.0090   -0.2727    0.2455   -0.2023    0.1516   -0.0947    0.0451    0.0094    0.0433    0.1096    0.1561    0.2158   -0.2445    0.2496
 0.0000    0.5431    0.4134    0.3143    0.2317    0.1604   -0.0958    0.0563   -0.0617    0.0119    0.0294   -0.0645    0.0962   -0.1161    0.1372    0.1548    0.1950    0.2157    0.2434   -0.2554    0.2451
-0.0000   -0.2286   -0.2287   -0.2288   -0.2283   -0.2265    0.2263    0.0338    0.2163   -0.2220    0.2231   -0.2228    0.2210   -0.2154    0.2075    0.2171    0.2365    0.2458    0.2538   -0.2607    0.2401


c =
-0.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0    0.0063         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0    0.0076         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0    0.0089         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0    0.0105         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0    0.0123         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0144         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0157         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0171         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0203         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0244         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0298         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0368         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0464         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0581         0         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0762         0         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.1063         0         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.1746         0         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.3324         0         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0781         0
      0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    7.1136
```

And running mex version for `[b,c] = eig_test_mex(input_matrix)` returns:

```
b=
0.0424+0.0000i  0.0881+0.0000i  0.0635+0.0000i  -0.1149+0.0000i 0.11+0.0000i    -0.1697+0.0000i 0.1285+0.0000i  0.0977+0.0000i  0.017+0.0000i   0.0382+0.0000i  -0.0283+0.0000i 0.0548+0.0000i  0.1493+0.0000i  -0.926+0.0000i  -0.1334+0.0000i 0.0085+0.0000i  -0.0442+0.0000i -0.0117+0.0000i -0.0251+0.0000i -0.0166+0.0000i 0+0.0000i
+0.0000i        0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i       -1+0.0000i
0.0392+0.0000i  0.1454+0.0000i  0.2241+0.0000i  -0.322+0.0000i  0.4286+0.0000i  -0.5139+0.0000i 0.4679+0.0000i  0.233+0.0000i   0.1086+0.0000i  0.0179+0.0000i  0.0219+0.0000i  -0.0178+0.0000i -0.0495+0.0000i 0.2919+0.0000i  0.0404+0.0000i  -0.002+0.0000i  0.0125+0.0000i  0.0029+0.0000i  0.0067+0.0000i  0.0042+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.1072+0.0000i  0.3145+0.0000i  0.4161+0.0000i  -0.3986+0.0000i 0.2592+0.0000i  0.0949+0.0000i  -0.4237+0.0000i -0.4495+0.0000i -0.2829+0.0000i -0.1305+0.0000i -0.0484+0.0000i -0.0143+0.0000i 0.0017+0.0000i  0.0102+0.0000i  0.001+0.0000i   -0.0001+0.0000i 0.0005+0.0000i  0.0001+0.0000i  0.0003+0.0000i  0.0002+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.1531+0.0000i  0.3698+0.0000i  0.3607+0.0000i  -0.1113+0.0000i -0.2103+0.0000i 0.3847+0.0000i  -0.0858+0.0000i 0.3538+0.0000i  0.4702+0.0000i  0.3391+0.0000i  0.1763+0.0000i  0.0641+0.0000i  -0.0241+0.0000i 0.0267+0.0000i  0.0076+0.0000i  -0.0001+0.0000i 0.0005+0.0000i  0.0002+0.0000i  0.0006+0.0000i  0.0003+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.1849+0.0000i  0.3654+0.0000i  0.2003+0.0000i  0.1799+0.0000i  -0.3636+0.0000i 0.0909+0.0000i  0.3224+0.0000i  0.179+0.0000i   -0.2586+0.0000i -0.4693+0.0000i -0.3832+0.0000i -0.207+0.0000i  0.074+0.0000i   0.028+0.0000i   -0.0173+0.0000i -0.0001+0.0000i 0.0044+0.0000i  0.0001+0.0000i  -0.0001+0.0000i 0.0003+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2079+0.0000i  0.3288+0.0000i  0.021+0.0000i   0.3295+0.0000i  -0.2029+0.0000i -0.2398+0.0000i 0.1914+0.0000i  -0.2836+0.0000i -0.2686+0.0000i 0.1676+0.0000i  0.4549+0.0000i  0.4038+0.0000i  -0.2178+0.0000i -0.0155+0.0000i 0.0758+0.0000i  -0.0001+0.0000i -0.0168+0.0000i 0.0001+0.0000i  0.0029+0.0000i  0+0.0000i       0+0.0000i
0.2255+0.0000i  0.2755+0.0000i  -0.1323+0.0000i 0.3254+0.0000i  0.0628+0.0000i  -0.2976+0.0000i -0.1457+0.0000i -0.2549+0.0000i 0.2223+0.0000i  0.3136+0.0000i  -0.1154+0.0000i -0.4488+0.0000i 0.3987+0.0000i  0.0857+0.0000i  -0.1958+0.0000i -0.0001+0.0000i 0.0623+0.0000i  0+0.0000i       -0.0114+0.0000i 0.0015+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2385+0.0000i  0.2128+0.0000i  -0.2394+0.0000i 0.2114+0.0000i  0.2566+0.0000i  -0.114+0.0000i  -0.2891+0.0000i 0.0922+0.0000i  0.2893+0.0000i  -0.1826+0.0000i -0.3266+0.0000i 0.1163+0.0000i  -0.4538+0.0000i -0.0966+0.0000i 0.3782+0.0000i  -0.0001+0.0000i -0.1658+0.0000i 0.0005+0.0000i  0.0419+0.0000i  -0.0058+0.0000i 0+0.0000i
0.2482+0.0000i  0.1468+0.0000i  -0.2951+0.0000i 0.0487+0.0000i  0.3013+0.0000i  0.1266+0.0000i  -0.1581+0.0000i 0.2923+0.0000i  -0.0583+0.0000i -0.3027+0.0000i 0.181+0.0000i   0.3142+0.0000i  0.1655+0.0000i  0.1012+0.0000i  -0.4695+0.0000i -0.0001+0.0000i 0.3338+0.0000i  -0.002+0.0000i  -0.1169+0.0000i 0.0224+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2552+0.0000i  0.0811+0.0000i  -0.3025+0.0000i -0.1089+0.0000i 0.2098+0.0000i  0.2657+0.0000i  0.0838+0.0000i  0.1782+0.0000i  -0.2952+0.0000i 0.058+0.0000i   0.2927+0.0000i  -0.2251+0.0000i 0.2658+0.0000i  0.0124+0.0000i  0.2826+0.0000i  0.0003+0.0000i  -0.4725+0.0000i 0.0085+0.0000i  0.2572+0.0000i  -0.0675+0.0000i 0+0.0000i
0.2593+0.0000i  0.0183+0.0000i  -0.2699+0.0000i -0.2242+0.0000i 0.0445+0.0000i  0.2463+0.0000i  0.2409+0.0000i  -0.0861+0.0000i -0.1748+0.0000i 0.3011+0.0000i  -0.1046+0.0000i -0.2511+0.0000i -0.2952+0.0000i -0.0743+0.0000i 0.1483+0.0000i  -0.0016+0.0000i 0.4018+0.0000i  -0.0282+0.0000i -0.4258+0.0000i 0.1667+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2613+0.0000i  -0.0393+0.0000i -0.2087+0.0000i -0.2793+0.0000i -0.1212+0.0000i 0.1072+0.0000i  0.2258+0.0000i  -0.2564+0.0000i 0.1135+0.0000i  0.1397+0.0000i  -0.3026+0.0000i 0.1904+0.0000i  -0.1556+0.0000i 0.0471+0.0000i  -0.3582+0.0000i 0.006+0.0000i   -0.0371+0.0000i 0.0796+0.0000i  0.4873+0.0000i  -0.3248+0.0000i 0+0.0000i
0.2618+0.0000i  -0.0908+0.0000i -0.1307+0.0000i -0.2741+0.0000i -0.2333+0.0000i -0.0674+0.0000i 0.0779+0.0000i  -0.2224+0.0000i 0.2707+0.0000i  -0.1694+0.0000i -0.0569+0.0000i 0.2701+0.0000i  0.2823+0.0000i  0.0733+0.0000i  0.0369+0.0000i  -0.0202+0.0000i -0.333+0.0000i  -0.1839+0.0000i -0.278+0.0000i  0.4791+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2611+0.0000i  -0.1354+0.0000i -0.0462+0.0000i -0.2193+0.0000i -0.2669+0.0000i -0.1994+0.0000i -0.1011+0.0000i -0.04+0.0000i   0.1829+0.0000i  -0.2745+0.0000i 0.2433+0.0000i  -0.0783+0.0000i 0.1598+0.0000i  -0.0344+0.0000i 0.3217+0.0000i  0.0569+0.0000i  0.253+0.0000i   0.3438+0.0000i  -0.1422+0.0000i -0.4801+0.0000i 0+0.0000i
0.2594+0.0000i  -0.173+0.0000i  0.0362+0.0000i  -0.1314+0.0000i -0.2244+0.0000i -0.2443+0.0000i -0.2162+0.0000i 0.1536+0.0000i  -0.0438+0.0000i -0.1025+0.0000i 0.2299+0.0000i  -0.2886+0.0000i -0.2298+0.0000i -0.0563+0.0000i -0.0665+0.0000i -0.1366+0.0000i 0.1931+0.0000i  -0.4999+0.0000i 0.3815+0.0000i  0.2085+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2569+0.0000i  -0.2036+0.0000i 0.1102+0.0000i  -0.0288+0.0000i -0.1272+0.0000i -0.1981+0.0000i -0.2221+0.0000i 0.2429+0.0000i  -0.2225+0.0000i 0.151+0.0000i   -0.0389+0.0000i -0.0976+0.0000i -0.2275+0.0000i 0.033+0.0000i   -0.3002+0.0000i 0.275+0.0000i   -0.2906+0.0000i 0.5187+0.0000i  -0.1234+0.0000i 0.2125+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2536+0.0000i  -0.2273+0.0000i 0.171+0.0000i   0.0716+0.0000i  -0.0057+0.0000i -0.0881+0.0000i -0.1303+0.0000i 0.1924+0.0000i  -0.2356+0.0000i 0.2586+0.0000i  -0.2494+0.0000i 0.2031+0.0000i  0.1126+0.0000i  0.0736+0.0000i  0.0141+0.0000i  -0.4544+0.0000i -0.1393+0.0000i -0.2791+0.0000i -0.2949+0.0000i -0.3911+0.0000i 0+0.0000i
0.2496+0.0000i  -0.2445+0.0000i 0.2158+0.0000i  0.1561+0.0000i  0.1096+0.0000i  0.0433+0.0000i  0.0094+0.0000i  0.0451+0.0000i  -0.0947+0.0000i 0.1516+0.0000i  -0.2023+0.0000i 0.2455+0.0000i  0.2727+0.0000i  0.009+0.0000i   0.2874+0.0000i  0.5901+0.0000i  0.275+0.0000i   -0.1434+0.0000i 0.2187+0.0000i  0.0927+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2451+0.0000i  -0.2554+0.0000i 0.2434+0.0000i  0.2157+0.0000i  0.195+0.0000i   0.1548+0.0000i  0.1372+0.0000i  -0.1161+0.0000i 0.0962+0.0000i  -0.0645+0.0000i 0.0294+0.0000i  0.0119+0.0000i  0.0617+0.0000i  -0.0563+0.0000i 0.0958+0.0000i  -0.5431+0.0000i 0.1604+0.0000i  0.4134+0.0000i  0.2317+0.0000i  0.3143+0.0000i  0+0.0000i
0.2401+0.0000i  -0.2607+0.0000i 0.2538+0.0000i  0.2458+0.0000i  0.2365+0.0000i  0.2171+0.0000i  0.2075+0.0000i  -0.2154+0.0000i 0.221+0.0000i   -0.2228+0.0000i 0.2231+0.0000i  -0.222+0.0000i  -0.2163+0.0000i -0.0338+0.0000i -0.2263+0.0000i 0.2286+0.0000i  -0.2265+0.0000i -0.2287+0.0000i -0.2283+0.0000i -0.2288+0.0000i 0+0.0000i

c=
7.1136   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        1.0781   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0.3324   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0.1746   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0.1063   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0.0762   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0581   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0464   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0368   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0298   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0244   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0203   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0171   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0157   0        0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0144   0        0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0063   0        0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0123   0        0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0076   0        0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0105   0        0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0.0089   0
0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

Ok, so the complex imaginary part is here again (i removed it from matrix `c` for clarity) but notice something. In eigenvalue matrix `c` there are the same values again but in reverse order. Why is that? At first glance is seems that values in `b` matrices are also the same just columns are reversed, but there are some differences. But as i understand this is ok.

**Finally**

I'm confused manly with two things. One is this transformation to complex numbers and the other one is this reverse ordering.

Does anyone have some insight on whats going on. Could first phenomena be resolved with updated MATLAB version or tool-chain? (I'm using MATLAB 2013, GCC 4.6 on Ubuntu 12.04). Second phenomena can probably be explained with math and implemented algorithms to compute eigenvectors/values. Any possible explanation?

Comment: I think the complex matrix is the eigen-vector, not the eigen-value, but you can take the magnitude (i.e. abs(eigen vector)) to obtain the eigen-value

Comment: If you expect the same answer, you have to implement some normalization process on top of the result. You can not rely on two different libraries returning the same answer, you can only rely on getting a correct answer.

Comment: For the complex part problem yes, this can be solved either with what @GameOfThrows suggested or with real(matrix). I am just curious why this happens.

Comment: @Daniel yes normalization can be solution to obtain the same result but what about the order of columns?

Comment: @micco - You are **not** guaranteed that `eig` will return the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the right order.  To ensure this, you will need to sort them.  You'd have to sort the eigenvalues first then rearrange the eigenvectors in the same ordering as the eigenvalues.

Comment: @rayryeng - ok I understand. I find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13704627/2428195) useful.

Comment: @micco - I was just about to give you that link :) Very nice.

Comment: Never mind the complex part, its just some residual error from math computations, the so called floating point errors. They are all `0.000i` in your code and I am pretty sure they are of order `e-10` the biggest.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes complex numbers can be easily resolved now that i know this. But it was hard for me to pin point the cause of my problem. When running C code, i was getting segmentation fault error and could not find the cause of it with GDB. I then debugged a mex function and found that the problem is within function [mvnrd()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html) which uses function [cholcov()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cholcov.html?searchHighlight=cholcov) which finally uses function [eig()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html?searchHighlight=eig).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not only one valid answer for a eigenvalue problem. Whenever dealing with such cases, best practice is to use or define a canonical form to convert equivalent answers to identical answers. To convert any answer into such a canonical form, I would apply the following steps:

1. Normalize all eigenvectors to length 1 (example: `[-0.4472,-0.4472,-0.4472,0.4472,0.4472]'` instead of `[-1,-1,-1,1,1]'`). Could be achieved using `b=bsxfun(@rdivide,b,sqrt(sum(b.^2,1)))`
2. For each eigenvectors with a negative value in the first component, take the negative value. (example: `[0.4472,0.4472,0.4472,-0.4472,-0.4472]'` instead of `[-0.4472,-0.4472,-0.4472,0.4472,0.4472]'`). Could be achieved using `b=bsxfun(@times,sign(b(1,:)),b)`
3. Sort eigenvectors and eigenvalues in ascending order of the eigenvalues. Could be achieved using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704627/2428195)

Please note that this is just one canonical form, not the canonical form. There might be canonical forms established but I have not found any reference so I basically put together what we discussed above to define a canonical form. Mathematically, applying such a canonical form results in a unique solution. In practice you will observe minor differences because of floating point precision errors.

Comment: One could also note that the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html) for the code generation version of `eig` (search for "eig" on that page) says that the outputs are always complex. This is likely because the C datatype has to be determined when generating code. Since the output may be complex for some inputs, it is set to always be complex.

Comment: @RyanLivingston thank you for documentation link. This is very useful.

Comment: @Daniel i accepted your answer manly because you nicely summarized our discussion and provided a way to ensure identical solutions.